# Create Sharepoint input controls via JSLINK

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, jslink

In my SharePoint 2013 project, I'm limited and can use only JavaScript. I need to implement custom column type. For example, in a list, I have "Address" field (i.e. long text) but in new/edit/display form, I want that field to be expanded (probably with JsLink) with additional fields: Address 2, Zip, etc... The idea is that I later fetch all data from additional inputs and save it as JSON in "Address" field. Later on, this model (i.e. Address) will be used as a template in other lists when needed.

I'd like to use integrated SharePoint controls and be able to exploit built in features, such as validation methods etc...

Is such thing possible with JsLink? If it is not, is there any other workaround?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. In this case you can create different columns of single line text(, i.e.,"Address Line1", "Street", "Zip", "City") and then create a new column of "Calculated" type namely "Full Address" and in the settings of that column you can specify to add all the previous columns namely,"Address Line1", "Street", "Zip", "City". 
Have a look at the image. Here, I have 3 columns of "FirstName", "LastName", and "FullName". In this the user only enters the value of "FirstName" and "LastName" and the "FullName" is automatically calculated. The image shows the settings of the "FullName" column.[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need. I need to create an input control programmatically, using JavaScript.